# Can you add public variables in a void method and return those public variables with the updated values

Tags: java

Ok im doing a project for school and I would post all of that code but I dont think its necessary. I just want to see if it's possible to do it in a very simple way so I can apply it into the bigger code. For the bigger code im using Android studio's to create an app.
So my problem is that I have a void method, I cant change it to any other value in the bigger code I think, but i'm trying to add numbers a public variable inside the method. Then later in another method trying to return the new value. Here is my code that im testing right now.

```
public class test{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        other h = new other();
        int num = h.getV();
        System.out.println(num);
    }
}

public class other{
    public int book = 0;
    public void g(){
        book++;
        book++;
    }
    public int getV(){
        return (book);
    }
}
```

It prints out 0, but I want it to print out 2. Also public void g() can't change value types.

Comment: You don't actually call `g()` so why would you expect the value 2?

Comment: Unrelated: read ab Java naming conventions. Then stick to your names. It is highly confusing to have a method called getV() return a value named books! You are constantly using these single character names which create nothing but confusion.

Comment: Well i guess what i'm asking is that why doesn't it increase book.

Comment: I know i'm supposed to use more descriptive variable naming but I just put this together in 5 mins, sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably call g() first before calling getV(). g() increments, and getV() returns the value of the variable named book.

```
public class test{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        other h = new other();
        h.g();
        int num = h.getV();
        System.out.println(num);
    }
}

public class other{
    public int book = 0;
    public void g(){
        book++;
        book++;
    }
    public int getV(){
        return (book);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, I don't know why I didn't that of this thanks again

Comment: It is better to define book field as private

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new other object called h storing an int called book that's equal to 0 initially.

g() will add one to the current value of book twice whenever its used so +2

getV() will print out whatever the current value of book in h is

since you never called h.g() in your main method, book in h is still 0 so that's what you're retrieving

Comment: Thanks so much for this information, and this was exactly what I needed to do! Thanks again